Comparing array sums with recursion
I had the following exam question in an intro to a CS course. I could not think of a proper solution for this.

Write a function in C that accepts two arrays, arr1 and arr2, and their common size, size, and checks if the sum of elements in the two arrays is equal with recursion.
Function signature:
bool isEqualSum(int arr1[], int arr2[], int size);

Examples:

For the input arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}, arr2 = {-1, 2, 12, -3}, size = 4, the function should return true, because the sum of the elements of both arrays is 10.
For the input arr1 = {1, 3, 3, 4}, arr2 = {-1, 2, 12, -3}, size = 4, the function should return false, because the sum of the elements of the first array (11) is different from the sum of the elements of the second array (10).

Note:

You may perform additional operations on the array elements, as long as the original values in the arrays remain unchanged before calling the function.
Do not use a temporary array.


My attempt at a solution:
bool areArraysEqual(int arr1[], int arr2[], int size) {
    // Base case: if size is zero, the arrays are equal
    if (size == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    // Check if the last elements of both arrays are equal
    if (arr1[size - 1] != arr2[size - 1]) {
        return false;
    }
    // Recursive call to check the remaining elements
    return areArraysEqual(arr1, arr2, size - 1);
}

But it returns false for the first example (quoted above). How can I solve this challenge?

What is the problem with the code you have written? Do you have a [mre] which calls it to show us? Have you tried to debug the code?

Oh I think I see the problem: You missed a crucial part of the task, to check if the sum of all elements in both arrays are equal.

I don't think it is possible to have such a recursive function with the given signature. You would need a helper recursive function wrapped in this one (unless you are "cheating" by using statics . or modifying the input arrays).

@EugeneSh. I think the reqs as I read them allow you to destroy the contents of the arrays in which case it should be possible even with this signature. (it only asks for "unchanged before")

@teapot418 Right, missed that note. When I read "recursive" I automatically presume "pure", otherwise it's dirty :)

Given that, you can "accumulate" the sums in the arrays themselves (that is element number i will contain the sum of original array up to element i, and compare them in the end.

Better yet, you can accumulate the difference between the sums, logically negate (NOT) and return it without comparing.

@EugeneSh.: I read that directive as being you could manipulate the contents of the array as long as you restore it when you are done.

@ScottHunter It says that the arrays should remain unchanged before calling the function. That is that some smart-a$$ students don't set them to all zeros and return true always.

@ScottHunter right, that makes more sense, but unfrobbing the values on the way back is fairly simple.

Are you allowed to use helper functions that uses only recursion?

I can use helper functions but the recursion has to occur in the isEqualSum function.

@EugeneSh.
How can I do this recursively when the value that is being returned is a bool type

@n.m.couldbeanAI. 100%
students which are taking now an advanced C programming course said to me that they don't know how to solve this

@Someprogrammerdude
The exam is on paper and I only was able to solve this with an envelop function (obviously easily) but the tester gave me 0 points because the recursion was happening there and not in the "main function".

An "intro to CS" course should not require you to use dirty tricks that would put your day job as a programmer at risk. Whoever thinks CS consists of such dirty tricks should not be allowed near students,

@EdenBager If you modify the arrays in-place, you don't care what the function returns except for the outermost iteration which is returning to the caller.

I am annoyed that the instructor would give this kind of coding problem. The requested functionality does not naturally map onto recursion. Basically you are using recursion instead of a loop (and unnecessarily wasting a bunch of stack memory in the process). Is the point that you can write any program with recursion instead of looping constructs? (Similar to "you can build any logic circuit with only NAND gates".) I don't like it.

Yes, you can do this without a helper function, with isEqualSum() alone doing the recursion. But instead of just showing you a program that works, I'll explain how to get there.
You probably already know the "natural" way to solve this. Write a for loop, stepping through the arrays, calculating the running sums. When the last loop is complete, compare the two sums to get your final answer.
For this assignment, the teacher wants you to use recursion instead of looping constructs. Teachers like this because anything you can solve with a "for" or "while" loop, you can solve with recursion (there is a formal proof for this). Apparently, this assignment is intended to demonstrate that to you.
There are two things to understand: first is "tail recursion", which is a good general model that you should learn and remember. The second thing is a trick that has less general applicability.
Here is an example of pure tail recursion:
bool tailRecursionDemo(int arr[], int size) {
    if (size == 1) {
        // Calculate final result and return it.
    }
    else {
        // Do required work at this level of recursion.
        return tailRecursionDemo(&arr[1], size - 1);
    }
}

What makes this tail recursion is that the last thing it does is return the value of the recursive call. Tail recursive code can automatically be converted into non-recursive looping by a smart compiler. (I don't know of any C compilers that can do that, but Clojure is a language that can do it.)
Unfortunately, this programming assignment cannot be written as a pure tail recursion. Here's the model that will work for you:
bool areArraysEqual(int arr1[], int arr2[], int size) {
    if (size == 1) {
        // Calculate final result and return it.
    }
    else {
        // Do some preliminary work.
        result = areArraysEqual(&arr1[1], &arr2[1], size - 1);
        // Do some cleanup. (This prevents it from being pure tail recursion.)
        return result;
    }
}

This us to the second thing to understand: the trick. For most of the execution of this program, you will be calculating the sums of the two arrays, using recursion instead of a "for" loop. You aren't going to compare anything until you've looped through the arrays, calculating the sums. So, how do you get recursion to calculate the sum? A more natural solution would be to pass a "sum_so_far" as a parameter into the areArraysEqual() function. But your teacher has fixed the calling sequence. So how do you pass the "sum_so_far" into the next recursive level?
The trick is to use the arrays themselves. You will overwrite an element of the array with the "sum_so_far", and then call the function recursively. Since this is modifying the array, you need to undo your overwrite after the recursive call returns. That's what's inside the "// Do some cleanup" section.
Remember to overwrite the element that the recursive call will have access to.

I would like to hear opinions: did I spoon-feed too much? Not enough? I sort-of feel like I gave too much info, but I also wanted to teach the tail recursion concept.

Thanks!! I'll try applying your suggestion and learn about tail recursion method.
Would let you where I got to!

As well, in your "tail recursion" example,
how would it affect the recursion if I'll return arr[1] instead of &arr[1]?
thanks,

The function signature is declared as:  "bool areArraysEqual(int arr1[], int arr2[], int size)".
In C, when a parameter is declared as "int arr1[]", it is the same as declaring it as "int *arr1". I.e. you must pass in a pointer. Passing in "arr[1]" passes in the value contained in "arr[1]" - an int, You can't do that. Each time you are calling the function, it is expecting a pointer to an array of integers. By passing in "&arr[1]", you are passing in the same array, skipping the first element ("arr[0]"), shrinking the array by 1.

Pseudocode of a possible solution:
bool areArraysEqual(int arr1[], int arr2[], int size) {
    // handle base cases smaller than 2
    ...
    // accumulate running totals in second element of each array (add first to second)
    ...
    // call recursively for subarrays starting at the second element
    bool ret = areArraysEqual(arr1+1, arr2+1, size-1);
    // undo changes
    ...
    return ret;
}

